Shopware 6 Products are hidden in Frontend
Shopware 6 - 6.4.20.2
I am having issues seeing my products that are active and selected for the sales channel in frontend of my page.
I checked in Shopware 6 Backend for the Category what products are inside, and there i see all the products that should appear in the frontend.
All categories and products are active, and the right sales channel is selected as well. The products are also assigned to the correct category.
To see the problem you can visit
https://sw6.boxolutions.de/verpackungspolstermaschinen
this is one category where way more products should be according to the backend. I also tried out dynamic product streams but this not seem to have an effect. In fact if i change anything manually on product level by selecting the desired category also has no impact.
I am a bit lost what to do here.
